# Inserting into a linked list in alphabetical order efficiently

Tags: java, linked-list, processing-efficiency

I am inserting items from a class I've created into a linked list, but I must find the correct index point to insert them to (so the items are in alphabetical order) before I add it.

I have some working code but it's ridiculously inefficient, taking 5 ish minutes on a semi-decent machine to add 10000 items. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

As of now, the only way I have managed to get it to work is as so. Any other methods end up adding items incorrectly (I'm guessing not correctly adding to the end of a list)

In the code shown, I am passing in a name (along with two other variables, that are irrelevant and already part of the itemClass) into the following code

```
if (llist.size() == 0) {
    llist.add(itemClass);
} 
else if (llist.get(0).name.compareTo(name)>0) {
    llist.add(0, itemClass);
} 
else if (llist.get(llist.size() - 1).name.compareTo(name) < 0) {
    llist.add(llist.size(), itemClass);
} 
else {
    int i = 0;
    while (llist.get(i).name.compareTo(name) < 0) {
        i++;
    }
    llist.add(i, itemClass);
}
```

This currently works, exactly as intended, but as said, takes incredibly long. I was just expecting something quicker, by possibly a large margin.

Comment: upon rethought, adding a binary search would possibly half(?) the time taken; but I have no idea how to implement this. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you specifically have to use a LinkedList ?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately. It seems counter intuitive in this case, but its the only way

Comment: Couldn't you use a TreeSet and then copy its content in the LinkedList ? That would be way faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have a linked list, but you're not making use of its actual "links"

Remove all calls to `get`

Instead of calling `get` you should use a listIterator.

Also, you should make use of the listIterator's `add` method